# How to make submit_tag always enabled?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, web, form-submit

I'm using Ruby on Rails to make a web app that allows the user to select items then export a file for download. However, after exporting once, the submit_tag button is disabled and would require a refresh.

Is it possible to keep the button enabled or re-enabled it after it's clicked? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In application.rb you can tell Rails to not disable submit tags with

```
config.action_view.automatically_disable_submit_tag = false
```

Or, for just that particular submit tag you can add this to your submit_tag...

```
data: { disable_with: false }
```